# Numpy indexing and slicing not working as intended! (Bug?)

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following code

```
import numpy as np
z = np.zeros((3,5,10,100))
indices = np.array([8, 0, 6, 1])
print(z[:,:,indices,:].shape)
print(z[1,:,indices,:].shape)
```

The output is as follows:

> (3, 5, 4, 100) 
>  
>   (4, 5, 100)

I want to assign `z[1,:,indices,:] = some_array` where `some_array` has shape `(5,4,100)` but that assignment throws an error as there is shape mismatch. 
 
I am confused about the second output (shape of `z[1,:,indices,:]`). I thought it should be `(5,4,100)`. Why are the first 2 axes getting switched? Is this a bug or is there any explanation why this is the correct behavior?

I got my code to go the desired thing by changing it to:

```
for i,index in enumerate(indices):
    z[1,:,index,:] = some_array[i]
```